# Blob would be exported before changes are made to the files

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I wrote a google script to generate resume and cover letter faster. It does the following

1. use ui.prompt to input content
2. create a folder and copy docs to the folder
3. replace keyword to content
4. convert docs to pdf in the folder

However, somehow the docs would be converted to PDFs before the keywords were replaced.

I have tried below but to no avail:

1. async awaits to wait for the main function before starting exporting PDFs
2. use utilities.sleep() to delay the exports

I have the main function and export function below for your information.

```js
function jobHuntAutomation() {

  //UI prompts for documents
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  var companyName = ui.prompt('Cover Letter', 'Enter Company Name: \n', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  var positionName = ui.prompt('Cover Letter', 'Enter Position Name: \n', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  var hiringManagerName = ui.prompt('Cover Letter', 'Enter Hiring Manager Name: \n', ui.ButtonSet.OK);

  //Create some file name strings
  var folderName = `${companyName.getResponseText()}_${positionName.getResponseText()}`
  var coverLetterName = `${companyName.getResponseText()}_${positionName.getResponseText()}_Coverletter`
  var resumeName = `${companyName.getResponseText()}_${positionName.getResponseText()}_Resume`

  //Get new folder object and Id
  var newFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(mainFolderId).createFolder(folderName);
  var newFolderId = newFolder.getId();
  var newFolderUrl = newFolder.getUrl()

  //Make a copy
  console.log('Making Copies')
  DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog(modalMessage('Making Copies...'), 'Status');
  var coverLetterId = DriveApp.getFileById(coverLetterTemplateId).makeCopy(coverLetterName, newFolder).getId();
  var resumeId = DriveApp.getFileById(resumeTemplateId).makeCopy(resumeName, newFolder).getId();

  //Status
  DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog(modalMessage('Updating Content...'), 'Status');

  //Get the coverLetter document body as a variable
  var coverLetterBody = DocumentApp.openById(coverLetterId).getBody();

  //Get the resume document body as a variable
  var resumeBody = DocumentApp.openById(resumeId).getBody();

  //Update Content
  doc.replaceText(keyword, input.getResponseText())
    .
    .
    .
  //you get the idea

  //export PDFs
  convertToPdf(resumeId, newFolder)
  convertToPdf(coverLetterId, newFolder)

  DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog(folderLink(newFolderUrl), 'Link');
}
```

```js
function convertToPdf(fileId, dest) {
  doc = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  docblob = doc.getAs('application/pdf');
  console.log(`Converting ${doc.getName()}...`)

  /* Add the PDF extension */
  docblob.setName(doc.getName() + ".pdf");
  
  // add file to the dest Folder
  dest.createFile(docblob);

}
```

It would be much appreciated if someone knows a solution to export PDFs AFTER the keywords are replaced. TIA

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. the docs need to be saveAndClose() before exporting so the changes would be flushed